# Visual Studio Debugger Allow in Firewall to access website

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have Visual studio community edition, i have created one form with web browser control when i run application in debugging mode webbrowser doesn't navigate any website it is because of windows 10 firewall is running, when i disable firewall it works properly.

I know i have to create firewall exception but not sure what all application need to choose.

Already created 3 rules in firewall to allow but my application still doesn't have internet access.

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
2. %ProgramFiles% (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\msvsmon.exe
3. My own application exe in debug folder

I need to access API and webbrowser.

Comment: The application is failing because it need to communicate with WWW.Microsoft.Com.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean? That every .NET application needs HTTP access to www.microsoft.com?

Comment: @Techie so you have a WinForms app with a WebBrowser component, and that component can't access the web? What _does_ your firewall say, exactly? Also, are you sure you're configuring the correct firewall? As in most cases, a firewall only blocks incoming connections. What's more likely is that you need proxy authentication, to allow outgoing requests.

Comment: There is a license verification that is made to Microsoft for Visual studio community edition which may be blocked.  You may want to use a sniffer and find out what internet connections (http) are being used by your application.  The firewall usually blocks based on port numbers.  Http usually use ports 80 or 8080, but may be using a different port number.

Comment: Visual studio is able to access internet as i can browse nugget packages from visual studio itself so i don't think that license verification is the reason, visual studio must accessing microsoft, the issue is with my custom application. which is not able to access when running in debug/release mode.

Answer (score 0):

In your Project folder > bin > Debug. Allow the 'projectname.vshost' file in the firewall.

Visual Studio uses '.vshost' file rather than exe file in Debug folder.